Reverse proxy a https website with Nginx Proxy Manager
I am trying to proxy a website that is hosted in other VPS with Ngix Proxy Manager. I am using port 443, but every time I try to enter a 502 error appear. Why could this be?
Tried to Request a SSL certificate and it says "Internal Error"
I also tried with http and port 80 and same 502 error.

Do you have any error logs that might provide more detail on the internal error? Do you have a simple code example that demonstrates the error?
